# Force livevalidation in a new line

Tags: html, prototypejs, livevalidation

I use this script to validate my forms, [livevalidation.com](http://livevalidation.com/). This works perfect, simple and efective, but now I have a problem, for this script the validator message appears next to the object where the error occurs. I want to force it instead to the side just below appears, and as much as I try, this has been impossible, try adding `\n` `\r` at the beginning of the line message, but nothing happens, I have tried `<br/>` but it does not work. How can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

For the sample on http://livevalidation.com/

```
.LV_validation_message {
  display: block;
}
```

is enough. For your own form styles it depends on hmm... your styles (maybe you are using floating elements or clearfixes or grid etc.).